# array of arrays: infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am dynamically adding/removing elements using javascript & jQuery.  For some reason my inner for loop is not exiting.  The counter continues to climb past the arrays length, and continues to add elements until the browser crashes.  When stepping through in Firefox debugger `groupList[i].length` shows the correct value.

Any ideas why the internal loop never returns false?

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

// array of arrays
var groupList = [];
groupList[groupList.length] = ["Japan", "Honda", "Toyota", "Nissan"];
groupList[groupList.length] = ["America", "Ford", "Dodge", "Chevrolet"];

// loop that creates a radio button from the first element in each array
for (var i = 0; i < groupList.length; ++i) {
    $j("#groupBtns").append("<label class=\"btn btn-primary active\" id=\"btn" + 
        groupList[i][0] + "\"><input type=\"radio\">" + groupList[i][0] + "</label>");
}

// function to add second group of radio button for remaining elements in selected array
function groupClick(group) {
    for (var i = 0; i < groupList.length; ++i) {
        if (group == groupList[i][0]) {
            // -- this is the infinite loop -- //
            for (var o = 1; 0 < groupList[i].length; ++o) {
                $j("#subGroupBtns").append("<label id=\"btn" + groupList[i][o] + 
                    "\" class=\"btn btn-primary\"><input type=\"radio\">" + 
                    groupList[i][o] + "</label>");
            }
        }
    }
}

// event listener
$j("#groupBtns").on('click', function (e) {
    groupClick($j(e.target).text())
});
```

note: the arrays will not always be the same length so I cannot use a static terminator for the loop.

Comment: It's rather dangerous to use the letter "o" as a variable name because it looks a lot like the number zero. (hint hint)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo :

```
for (var o = 1; 0 < groupList[i].length; ++o) {
```

You are doing `0 < groupList[i].length`, always resulting to true if there's a length.

Should be :

```
for (var o = 1; o < groupList[i].length; ++o) {
```

Comment: Definitely done using "o" as a variable in nested loops.  "0" and "o" look too much alike and are too close on the keyboard.